# PHP- Run Python query with php arguments

Tags: php, python, variables

I have a very small doubt regarding the execution of a python script using php. I want to use 2 php variables `$starttime` and `$endtime` in my python execution command but I am unable to do that.

I have used these variables in single quotes, double quotes, without quotes ,etc but haven't been successful yet. 
Code:

```
<?php
$starttime="something1";
$endtime="something2";
shell_exec('python abc.py $starttime $endtime >xyz.csv')
?>
```

Output is stored in csv file. If I use `something1` `something2` the execution command, everything works normal. I wanna use these 2 variables. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that anything in `''` is not being parsed but taken as literal string. If you want the variable values to get in the `shell_exec` argument, maybe do this:

```
<?php
$starttime="something1";
$endtime="something2";
shell_exec("python abc.py $starttime $endtime >xyz.csv");
?>
```

Next thing is, check if [shell_exec](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) works. For example does this output expected

```
<?php
$starttime="something1";
$endtime="something2";
echo shell_exec("echo $starttime $endtime");
?>
```

It should dump something like "something1 something2". If it doesn't, probably `shell_exec` does not work at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! That worked. Using execution statement in double quotes solved the purpose..

Answer (score 0):

if you want variable values to be executed then you can utilize double quotes in your code
Ex.

```
<?php
$starttime="something1";
$endtime="something2";
shell_exec("python abc.py $starttime $endtime >xyz.csv");
?>
```

OR

if you want the variables to be present there. then you can utilize the following.

```
<?php
$starttime="something1";
$endtime="something2";
shell_exec("python abc.py $$starttime $$endtime >xyz.csv");
?>
```